# How to lazy load an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, seo, lazy-loading

```
.image--about {
    background: url(../img/ZIZF.gif) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover
}
```

I have this CSS. I want to use lazy loading to following images that I load via CSS, can you please help me out?

Comment: That might help: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/lazy-loading-css-background-images-for-better-website-loading-performance/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it possible to apply lazy loading by css but it 's possible with **HTML** by adding single attribute `loading="lazy"`

```html
<img src="myimage.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="..." />
```

other values for loading like `eager` and `auto`

others method will required JavaScript check this  [Five Ways to Lazy Load Images for Better Website Performance](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/)

Comment: Hey I have tried adding the folloewing attribute in images , but i just want to add it in css , my image loads via css , if you could help me so

Comment: I look for it but so far there is now way to load image by css only there is servals methods  that include JavaScript and a single method as I mention in my answer

Comment: check this for more info https://web.dev/lazy-loading-images/